# SQL: query to categorize items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `product`

```
area  productname   count
a1     p1            5
a2     p2            6
a1     p2            9
a2     p3            8
a1     p3            1
```

I want it to be like this; if it is possible in SQL, I'm using SQL Server

```
a1     count(p1)    count (p2)  count(p3)
a2     count(p1)    count (p2)  count(p3)
.
.
an     count(p1)    count (p2)  count(p3)
```

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query You need `Dynamic PIVOT` to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific problem you are trying to solve, the following query will work. Evaldas suggested the link that also provides a great example for dynamic pivoting.

```
select area, p1, p2, p3
from
(select area, productname, counter from test) t
pivot 
(
  min(counter)
  for productname in (p1, p2, p3)
) as piv
order by area;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ef59/19